# Xcode linker error Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have this error:

"_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey", referenced from:
      _UnityAdsIosBridge_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m2540915321 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityAds_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m990779160, _UnityAdsExternal_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m2195936698 , _UnityAdsIosBridge_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m2540915321 , _UnityAdsExternal_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m2195936698_MetadataUsageId , _UnityAds_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m990779160_MetadataUsageId , _UnityAdsIos_getRewardItemDetailsWithKey_m1590730138 )
  "_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem", referenced from:
      _UnityAdsIosBridge_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m1608394056 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityAdsIosBridge_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m1608394056, _UnityAdsIos_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m1509436557 , _UnityAds_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m2595080192_MetadataUsageId , _UnityAdsExternal_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m3235109297_MetadataUsageId , _UnityAdsExternal_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m3235109297 , _UnityAds_setDefaultRewardItemAsRewardItem_m2595080192 )

And other. Tell me how you can solve this problem. I did not find the right solution, although I struggle with this not for the first day.

Comment: This looks like some .Net code is left out of the build. Did you try disabling all the stripping options in Unity's build settings?

Comment: No. Tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you tell me?

Comment: Check the build settings for the iOS platform. You can do this by clicking "platform settings" in the build dialog. Find the option which reads "stripping", change it to no stripping at all, try your build again.

Comment: stripping level - disabled

Comment: Build to iOS with IL2CPP or Mono2x?

Comment: Could you give me your skype to discuss this issue, since it is very interesting for me?

Comment: You can use mono for test builds on 32 bit devices, but you'll need il2cpp for universal builds which you can publish to the app store.

Comment: il2cpp with stripping level "disabled" unable to solve the problem

Comment: bitcode yes or no?